# "klagen" or "beklagen"

Tags: meaning, difference, usage

I have seen two ways of saying "I can't complain":

> Ich kann nicht klagen.
>   Ich kann mich nicht beklagen.

Do they mean the same?
If so, which one is more commonly used?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the meaning is identical. The first sentence *could* have a different meaning (lawsuit), though.

Which is more common is hard to answer. My personal opinion is that "Ich kann mich nicht beklagen" is more common.

According to [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Ich%20kann%20nicht%20klagen%2C%20Ich%20kann%20mich%20nicht%20beklagen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CIch%20kann%20nicht%20klagen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CIch%20kann%20mich%20nicht%20beklagen%3B%2Cc0), however, their uses are almost equally frequent; with a slight tendency towards "Ich kann nicht klagen".

You're fine either way.